# NewPolish - unconventional translator in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

**Hello everyone!**

In today's assignment I had to complete a rather unusual translator, take a look at my solution, tell me what I can do to make it better and show off yours!

Write a function that translates some text into New Polish and vice versa. Polish is translated into New Polish by taking the last letter of each word, moving it to the beginning of the word and adding `ano` at the beginning. `Tom has a cat'` becomes `['Anomto anosha anoa anotca']`.

```
def new_polish_translator(input):
   
    result = ''

    content = input.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').replace('?', '').replace('-', '')
        
        #Dzieli na linie bez wchodzenia do nowej linii (\n)
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in content.split("\n")]
    lines = [line for line in lines if len(line) > 0]

        #sprawdza czy nie jest przetlumaczony
    if all(line[-3::] == 'ano' for line in lines for word in line.split(' ')):
        result = ' '.join(lines)
        
        #sprawdza czy nie jest
    else:
        result = ' '.join('ano' + word[-1] + word[0:-1] for line in lines for word in line.split(' '))
        result = result.capitalize()
        
    return result


new_polish_translator("Tom has a cat")
```

result:

```
'Anomto anosha anoa anotca'
```

**Have a great day!**

Comment: Not super important, but I'll just note that this is basically just a variation of "Pig Latin".

Answer (score 2):

Your code is reasonable, but it does get tripped up if the text (`input`)
contains multiple adjacent spaces or the cleaned text (`content`) ends up
containing multiple adjacent spaces. It also could be simplified here and
there. Some suggestions to consider: (1) parameterize the function so the user
can control which punctuation characters to remove; (2) since the algorithm is
fundamentally a word-based translation, it makes sense to convert the text to
words early; (3) the check for already-translated text is not robust to
capitalization; and (4) use the no-argument form of `split()` to avoid the bug
noted above. Here's one way to make those changes:

```
def new_polish_translator(text, replace = ',.?-'):
    # Remove unwanted punctuation.
    for char in replace:
        text = text.replace(char, '')

    # Convert to words.
    words = text.split()

    # Translate, unless the text is already New Polish.
    prefix = 'ano'
    if all(w.lower().startswith(prefix) for w in words):
        np_words = words
    else:
        np_words = [prefix + w[-1] + w[0:-1] for w in words]

    # Return new text.
    return ' '.join(np_words).capitalize()
```

As you know already, this problem raises some tricky questions related to how
the algorithm defines a "word". Simply splitting on whitespace and removing a
few common punctuation markers will fail to handle a variety of human language
inputs reasonably. There are other types of punctation (colon, semicolon, dash,
and some weird ones), some words have internal punctuation (apostrophe), some
words contain or even start with digits, some words convey additional meaning
with capitalization, and some texts care about internal whitespace. Consider
this specimen from Ogden Nash, and notice the details of spacing and
punctuation lost during translation:

```
# English.

The camel has a single hump;
The dromedary, two;
Or else the other way around.
I'm never sure. Are you?

# New Polish.

Anoeth anolcame anosha anoa anoesingl ano;hump anoeth anoydromedar ano;two anoro anoeels anoeth anorothe anoywa anodaroun anomi' anorneve anoesur anoear anouyo
```

Is there a a **practical** way to make a translator that preserves more of
those details? One approach is to use a basic tokenizing technique to decompose
the input text into various tokens, some of which will be preserved as-is and
some of which will be word-translated. These tokenizers are easy to build
because they follow a simple pattern: try to match a sequence of regular
expressions; stop on the first match; emit a `Token`; then re-enter the loop.
In these situations, it helps to define some simple data-objects to represent
search patterns and tokens. A sketch is shown below. It is purposely unfinished
in the sense that it is missing some error handling (eg, checking that the
patterns exhaust the text) and
it doesn't try to preserve the original word capitalization. But those
improvements are fairly easy to add if you are so inclined.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re

Pattern = namedtuple('Pattern', 'kind regex')
Token = namedtuple('Token', 'kind text')

def new_polish_translator(text):
    # Define the search patterns.
    patterns = [
        Pattern('whitespace', re.compile('\s+')),
        Pattern('word', re.compile('[A-Za-z]+')),
        Pattern('other', re.compile('\S+')),
    ]

    # Translate only Token(kind=word). Preserve the rest.
    words = []
    for tok in tokenize(text, patterns):
        if tok.kind == 'word':
            w = tok.text
            words.append('ano' + w[-1] + w[0:-1])
        else:
            words.append(tok.text)

    # Return joined text.
    return ''.join(words)

def tokenize(text, patterns):
    pos = 0
    limit = len(text)
    while pos < limit:
        for p in patterns:
            m = p.regex.match(text, pos = pos)
            if m:
                txt = m.group(0)
                pos += len(txt)
                yield Token(p.kind, txt)
                break
```

Output:

```
anoeTh anolcame anosha anoa anoesingl anophum;
anoeTh anoydromedar, anootw;
anorO anoeels anoeth anorothe anoywa anodaroun.
anoI'm anorneve anoesur. anoeAr anouyo?
```